# Charts disappearing when refreshing page from cache in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, caching, charts

I'm building pages with ASP.Net (Framework 4) and Microsoft Charts.

Those charts require heavy queries to the database and I would like to cache them to prevent my users from overflowing my database with useless queries.

I succeeded in caching my page **but my charts disappear when the page is refreshed from cache**. I've read that it's because my chart's images are not stored in the cache.

How can I proceed to avoid my charts from disappearing when the page is reloaded from cache and so they would generate as few queries as possible?

**More informations :**

- I have a ASPX page that contains a ASCX control.
- In this control, I have a ***System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart*** component, that is populated within the OnLoad method, with a heavy database access.
- I want to cache my ASPX page and therefore my ASCX control to avoid querying the database to often.
- When using this markup ***<%@OutputCache Duration="15" ... %>***, when hitting F5 my page refreshes itself from cache but my Chart is not lost.

Comment: In order for anybody to give you any kind of help, please post code snippets how you assign the data to the chart components, as well as in which method (Page_Load()? you are doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was some configuration problem within the Web.config file :

I edited this line as follow :

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" 
value="storage=file;timeout=360;
dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;
webDevServerUseConfigSettings=true;
deleteAfterServicing=false;"/>
```

Then I simply entered the following command in my ASPX file (on Top, right under the ***<%@ Page .../>*** markup ) :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" Location="Server" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

Now my page refreshes itself properly from the cache, including my charts.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the data from DB (that is used to draw charts)

Comment: Which mean I have to manually manage all the stuff ? Using the "Cache" object and managing the cache duration by myself ?